# Using a loop to print output sorted by column in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, columnsorting

I have a large dataframe in R like this:

```
portfolio ctry numb weight ticker 
MP         US  500   0.3    des
MP         UK  650   0.2    jkr
LEN        GR  800   0.4    fop
LEN        US  400   0.2    dpi
CC         CA  500   0.3    sab   
CC         GR  400   0.5    ctu
```

At the end I would like to show it like this or anything which looks similar to this:

```
- MP - 
US  500   0.3    des
UK  650   0.2    jkr
- LEN - 
GR  800   0.4    fop
US  400   0.2    dpi
- CC - 
CA  500   0.3    sab   
GR  400   0.5    ctu
```

Which means I would like to get an output where the data is sorted by the first column (portfolio). I tried several possibilities to create a loop but doesn't work. I'm pretty new to R and if anyone could point me in the right direction it would be a great help!

Comment: you can try something like: `df[order(df$portfolio, decreasing=T),]`

Comment: Three questions: what have you already tried? And why did it not work to your satisfaction? And what do you want to do with your output?

Comment: Probably something like `split(df[-1], df[1])`